# How to take a screenshot of the front window from the command line?

Tags: screen-capture

The `screencapture` utility has a `-w` switch which allows capturing the front window, but only after highlighting the window and getting a click from the user.

Is there any way to capture the front window non-interactively using some shell command?

Comment: I can't find any `screenshot` command on my Mac running OS X 10.8.3. Is it an addition you've installed? Which is your OS version?

Comment: @jaume corrected to `screencapture`

Answer (score 2):

The `-l` option allows capturing a window by ID. It is only shown in the help message and not on the man page.

I don't know any way to [find the window IDs](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/56561/how-do-i-find-the-windowid-to-pass-to-screencapture-l) that would work with all applications though. This doesn't work with Preview, Activity Monitor, or Chrome:

`screencapture -l $(osascript -e 'tell application (path to frontmost application as text) to id of window 1') /tmp/screencapture.png`